# WPF combobox style properties

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, wpf-style

What is the diffrence between:

- DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate
- ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector
- ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle
- ControlTemplate
- ComboBox.ItemTemplate

How can I configure different style and data of the combobox list and the selected value?

For example in the Combobox list there will be a list of all the days with checkbox and after selection of the combobox the combobox content will show a blue TextBlock with the text "Select X items" by the number of days that been selected in the list?

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Comment: Thank you but it's not relevant to most of the things that related to ComboBox like CellTemplate, ItemTemplateSelector, ItemTemplateSelector and ControlTemplate and also I still don't know how to implement my example. Any ideas?

Comment: Most of the items are completely unrelated and too broad to cover all this in one answer. Please post specific question may be after reading out MSDN documentation for all the listed items.

Comment: What is the difference between apples & pears? :))